# Alternative option of conversational actions for Google Home Nest Mini

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I'm very new to google actions and I got one project which is made by using conversational actions. (You can try it in google assistant talk to help me sleep)

And as you all know conversational actions will be deprecated soon, and I try a lot for alternatives for Google Home Nest Mini but I'm stuck and I can not force my end user to install any android application.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not provide API for configuring the smart home actions.
You can open a ticket in this regards on the [public issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/) and we will forward your request to the internal team to see what we can do in this regard.